# python sgdclassifier sklearn

Tags: python, sql, machine-learning

I am using Python 2.7 and I installed sklearn.

The data_io code

```
import csv
import json
import os
import pickle
import psycopg2

def paper_ids_to_string(ids):
return " ".join([str(x) for x in ids])

conn_string = None

def get_db_conn():
global conn_string
if conn_string is None:
    conn_string = get_paths()["postgres_conn_string"]
if "##AskForPassword##" in conn_string:
    password = raw_input("PostgreSQL Password: ")
    conn_string = conn_string.replace("##AskForPassword##", password)
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
return conn

def get_paths():
paths = json.loads(open("SETTINGS.json").read())
for key in paths:
    paths[key] = os.path.expandvars(paths[key])
return paths

def save_model(model):
out_path = get_paths()["model_path"]
pickle.dump(model, open(out_path, "w"))

def load_model():
in_path = get_paths()["model_path"]
return pickle.load(open(in_path))

def write_submission(predictions):
submission_path = get_paths()["submission_path"]
rows = [(author_id, paper_ids_to_string(predictions[author_id])) for author_id in predictions]
writer = csv.writer(open(submission_path, "w"), lineterminator="\n")
writer.writerow(("AuthorId", "PaperIds"))
writer.writerows(rows)

def get_features_db(table_name):
conn = get_db_conn()
query = get_features_query(table_name)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
res = cursor.fetchall()
return res

def get_features_query(table_name):
query = open("feature_query.sql").read().strip()
return query.replace("##DataTable##", table_name)
```

This is train code

```
import data_io
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

def main():
    print("Getting features for deleted papers from the database")
    features_deleted = data_io.get_features_db("TrainDeleted")

    print("Getting features for confirmed papers from the database")
    features_conf = data_io.get_features_db("TrainConfirmed")

    features = [x[2:] for x in features_deleted + features_conf]
    target = [0 for x in range(len(features_deleted))] + [1 for x in range(len(features_conf))]

    print("Training the Classifier")
    classifier = SGDClassifier(alpha=0.0001, class_weight='auto', epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.0, fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='optimal', loss='log', n_iter=5, n_jobs=1, penalty='l2', power_t=0.5, random_state=None, rho=None, shuffle=False, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
    classifier.fit(features, target)

    print("Saving the classifier")
    data_io.save_model(classifier)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

and this predict code

```
from collections import defaultdict
import data_io

def main():
print("Getting features for valid papers from the database")
data = data_io.get_features_db("ValidPaper")
author_paper_ids = [x[:2] for x in data]
features = [x[2:] for x in data]

print("Loading the classifier")
classifier = data_io.load_model()

print("Making predictions")
predictions = classifier.predict_proba[:,1]
predictions = list(predictions)

author_predictions = defaultdict(list)
paper_predictions = {}

for (a_id, p_id), pred in zip(author_paper_ids, predictions):
    author_predictions[a_id].append((pred, p_id))

for author_id in sorted(author_predictions):
    paper_ids_sorted = sorted(author_predictions[author_id], reverse=True)
    paper_predictions[author_id] = [x[1] for x in paper_ids_sorted]

print("Writing predictions to file")
data_io.write_submission(paper_predictions)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

when I try to run, I have the following typeerror:
predictions = classifier.predict_proba[:,1]
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not subscriptable

What should I do?

Comment: Please post a minimalistic reproduction script instead (I am sure you can trim down this example to 10/20 line in a single script). Also always read and provide the complete traceback of the error if you want other people to quickly help. Usually the traceback has the filenames and line numbers of all the functions involved when the error happens. Put yourself in the position of people who might try to answer your questions on StackOverflow. This kind of question looks like "Please debug my code instead of me".

Answer (score 0):

predict_proba is a method.  You need to call it with a feature matrix or vector.